# ANT - How can I exclude a jar file from the war

Tags: ant, jboss

I want to exclude the 3 cxf jars from the war file so that those jars will be loaded from jboss 7.2 server. I am using the below code for that but jars are not getting removed.

```
 <war destfile="dist/@{project-web}.war" webxml="WebRoot/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <fileset dir="WebRoot"/>
    <lib dir="WebRoot-AL/WEB-INF/lib">
        <exclude name="cxf-core-3.2.5*.jar" />
        <exclude name="cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.2.5*.jar" />
        <exclude name="cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.5*.jar" />
    </lib>
    <!--lib dir="WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib" /-->
    <classes dir="${bin.hudson}/extractor"/>
 </war>
```

Is the above mentioned script correct? If not, how can I do this?

Comment: It's because those files are also located inside the `fileset` that you specified above. Either set them as excludes there as well, or make sure your libs are located elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the files are present only at one path(webroot-al/web-inf/lib) and no where else present. I have already set right with exclude tag.could you please explain in detail?

Comment: Thanks CAustin, As you said I have excluded those files from file set also. It's working now.